# Creating permanent tile URL in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, tile-server

Is there a way to create a permanent tile server URL for an image?

Earlier I had used `ee.Image.getMap()` to get a URL like - [https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/planet-webapp/maps/74f663849d42e3e8e71ff9a118942791-d7e8513d1d7c2b8cd15147beb65f2c17/tiles/{x}/{y}/{z}.png](https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/planet-webapp/maps/74f663849d42e3e8e71ff9a118942791-d7e8513d1d7c2b8cd15147beb65f2c17/tiles/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bz%7D.png)

What's the validity of such URLs?

I would prefer a URL for long term use once generated.

I am working on an open-source project which needs to show satellite imagery and analysis for multiple years, for 140+ planting projects. I need a way to automate the imagery generation process whenever a new location is added and save the tile URLs in the backend and use it.

This is how it will look on frontend - https://planet-webapp-jrckm5v45.vercel.app/yucatan-reforestation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth Engine does not currently provide guarantees about the expiration time of map tile URLs, and this has changed in the past. You should not expect them to continue to be usable over multiple days.

The normal way map IDs/URL templates are used is to request a new one *on every page load*. There shouldn't be a problem with reusing one for multiple users in the short term, but I would suggest that you should definitely avoid putting any map URLs in your database.

Comment: Thanks, @kevin, how long can I cache them before they seize to exist? an hour, a day, a month? I am afraid that generating a new one on every load will slow down the site.

Comment: @SarveshWarge As I said in the first paragraph: there is not currently any guarantee about their expiration time.